# Detect Blackberry Browser on google Sites

Tags: javascript, blackberry, google-sites

I'm using google calendar embedded on a Google Site.

BlackBerry users are reporting errors so I want to redirect them to another page.

I tried to add this code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">   
   var ua = navigator.userAgent;
   var url = "http://optimizedmobile.yoursite.com/";
   if (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0)
   {
      if (ua.indexOf("WebKit") >= 0)
      {
         window.location = url;
      }
   }
</script>
```

using the [instructions provided here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en), but it's not working.  I tested the code in a html file that I created and it works.

So, any other ideas to include the code on the page?  Do you think the code is not supported by Google sites?

Any other ideas to redirect BB users?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know exactly **which** BlackBerry devices you're trying to detect.  Unfortunately, the answer is different for many of them.

From [this BlackBerry.com reference document](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862), some UserAgent examples:

> **User Agent in BlackBerry 10**
>
> ```
> Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; <Device Type>) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/<BB Version #> Mobile Safari/537.10+
> ```
>
> **User Agent in BlackBerry Tablet OS**
>
> ```
> Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.0 Safari/535.8+
> ```
>
> **User Agent in BlackBerry 6 and BlackBerry 7**
>
> ```
> Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry AAAA; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/X.X.X.X Mobile Safari/534.11+
> ```
>
> **User Agent in BlackBerry Device Software 4.2 to 5.0**
>
> ```
> BlackBerry9000/5.0.0.93 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/179
> ```

So, it looks to me like the exact string `BlackBerry` will only show up in user agents for devices with Java OS version 4.2 - 7.1.  And, among those, only those with OS 6.0 - 7.1 will be using the `WebKit` browser.

So, I think you just need to add some more cases to your `if` statement, to detect all BlackBerry devices.